# Overriding Unity3D built-in CharacterController

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I create a new C# script called `CharacterController`, Unity will display this warning:

> Script 'CharacterController' has the same name as built-in Unity component. AddComponent and GetComponent will not work with this script.

Can I somehow override this (so that `AddComponent` and `GetComponent` will work)? It doesn't seem like Unity cares about namespace for this.

Comment: It's a hell lot easier to just name your script something different.

Comment: But CharacterController is such a nice name for a character controller ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity has already stated that they [won't fix this](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/importing-a-class-with-the-same-name-as-a-built-in-unity-component-gets-incorrect-import-warning).

> This particular case has been investigated thoroughly and we have decided, in the interests of protecting the stability and features of Unity for users that rely upon the affected versions, to not address this issue.

So the solution is to use a different script name.